# Why typescript doesn't allow to check equality of two generic varaibles?

Tags: typescript

```
function f1<T, U>(x: T, y: U) {
  return x === y
}
```

Why does Typescript complain? I'm not sure I fully understand what does the compilation error message means.

Compilation error:

> TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T' and 'U' have no overlap.

Comment: Your two parameters have strictly different types; `'1' === 1` is always false, for example. If they could be the same type, you need to express that in the function signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the message itself. In your case, T and U have no overlap because they represent two different types. TypeScript purpose is to help you to prevent those cases.

So it would work if you tell the compiler that y could be possible to be x. Like

```
function f1<T, U>(x: T, y: U | T) {
    return x === y;
}
```

or

```
function f1<T, U extends T>(x: T, y: U) {
    return x === y;
}
```